# VBA jump to next column

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with VBA code that will make the selected cell after pressing enter to not be the one below but instead the top of the next column.

I hope the image I uploaded makes more sense to what my request is.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddXrS.png)

Comment: Selecting the cell is easy `ActiveCell.Next.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Select` responding to the Enter key is going to be tough.

Comment: @TinMan ActiveCell.Next ?  +1 Nice.

Comment: please go back and read [ask] and include a [mcve] (i.e., the necessary code which produces this behavior).

Comment: respond to the enter key with Application.OnKey ? set that during the Workbook_Open event maybe? or, just shortcut it with the Worksheet_Change event which is basically the same thing.

Comment: Not sure of an easy solution to this, but one alternative (if this is something you are doing for yourself) is to select the range where you want to have this occur.  For example, if you select A1:C10 and start entering data in A1, each [Enter] will bring you to the next cell down until you reach A10, after which it will go to B1.  Of course any action that ends the selection will stop this behavior.

Comment: @DavidZemens I forgot about the `OnKey()` event.  That is the way to go!  Im glad that I didn't post my keylogger..lol.

Comment: @TinMan vba hacker tricks?!? whoa

Comment: Glad that I am not going to use this workbook - navigating and editing values will be a nightmare (imaging entering "5" in a cell and suddenly finding your self in a totally different column)!

Comment: @AJD its house of mirrors excel version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in ThisWorkBook. You dont have to actually close then open the workbook, you can just F8 through this code to set it for this session:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "jumpToNextColumn"
    Application.OnKey "~", "jumpToNextColumn"
End Sub
```

And this in a module:

```
Sub jumpToNextColumn()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveCell.column + 1).Select
End Sub
```

Or as tinMan puts it:

```
Sub jumpToNextColumn()
    ActiveCell.Next.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: @TinMan thank you for advice brother and sorry if i stole ur thunder for this one, just love them REP points LOL. See edits.

Comment: NIce edits, very clean!  I was wrong about ActiveSheet, BTW.