# Set Color for next column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting the color of my range by following code and it is working fine. I want to set the same color for the next column in the for each loop too. Set the same for range B5:B219

```
Dim companyCol As Range
   

For Each companyCol In wsLookup.Range("A5:A219")

    If companyCol.Value = "16247773" Then
        companyCol.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        ' here I want to sent the same color for next column

        
    ElseIf companyCol.Value = "49407" Then
        companyCol.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        ' here I want to sent the same color for next column
        
    ElseIf companyCol.Value = "16724889" Then
        companyCol.Interior.ColorIndex = 17
        ' here I want to sent the same color for next column
    
    Else '16777215
        companyCol.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
        ' here I want to sent the same color for next column

End If
Next companyCol
```

referred this link but not able to solve the issue.

[VBA jump to next column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223460/vba-jump-to-next-column)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want columns A and B to be the same color?  Change range A5:A219 to A5:B219.

Comment: I tried this before posting and it is not working. it is only changing the color of A column only

Comment: Is there any conditional formatting in the sheet that conflicts with it?

Comment: there is formatting on the sheet which work for col c.

Comment: After making the change above to include `B` too, add `If companyCol.Column = 2 Then Stop` inside the loop and then when it stops, use `F8` to step thru the logic and see where it is not doing what  you expect.

Comment: Thanks. But how will I set the color of Col 2 based on the value in col 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Dim c As Range, ci As Long
   
For Each c In wsLookup.Range("A5:A219")

    Select Case c.Value 'select case is more efficient here
        Case "16247773": ci = 20
        Case "49407": ci = 44
        Case "16724889": ci = 17
        Case Else: ci = -4142
    End Select
    'color cell `c` and the next one to the right
    c.Resize(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = ci

Next c
```